# How to plot two variables as histogram in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, distribution

How to make histogram-style bar-plot of continuous data in python?

The data I have looks like this with simple plt.plot(x,y) (x-axis is not normalized, but is real data from 0 to 1):

[image]

So obviously I would need to plot some kind of distribution, but I don't know what is it called that I am looking for. I want the x and y axis to stay the same, so I don't want to plot histogram of one of the variables, but instead of plotting every point, I want to plot only the average values of y between some intervals of x. I could do this with plt.bar(bins, y-columns), and I know how to calculate the bins, but how to find automatically the corresponding y-column values?

I suppose there must be an easy and automated way of doing what I described, however, I can't find it.

Comment: Have you tried `plt.hist()`? [Docs here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html). If that doesn't work for you, then please provide a [mcve] including sample data and code for what you've tried already

Answer (score 3):

Might this tutorial may help you, 
https://cmdlinetips.com/2019/02/how-to-make-histogram-in-python-with-pandas-and-seaborn/

```
sns.distplot(df['lifeExp'],  kde=False, label='Africa')

df =gapminder[gapminder.continent == 'Americas']
sns.distplot(df['lifeExp'],  kde=False,label='Americas')

# Plot formatting
plt.legend(prop={'size': 12})
plt.title('Life Expectancy of Two Continents')
plt.xlabel('Life Exp (years)')
plt.ylabel('Density')
```

Result as:

[image: result]